# 19.10: Does gvfsd-admin require authentication?

Tags: dual-boot, mysql, 19.10

I have a mysql 8 running on an ubuntu 19.10 on a desktop computer (a new think station).

Computer has a dual boot and two SSD hard drives (500gb and 1TB), both of then partitioned. In the small one I have the OSs and the big one is reserved to data. In the small one Ubuntu has like less than 200gb and in the big one a little bit less than 600gb. Root `/` is the 200gb while `/home` is the 600gb.

I moved the mysql storage to `/home/data/mysql` so I don't run out of space since I'm going to load a good chuck of data (~100gb 500 million rows).

I'm not usually on the desktop of the computer but accessing via ssh.

However, I've seen already twice a windows asking for authentication for `gvfsd-admin` process. I grant it and then the window stays there forever.

What is going on?

[image: auth_promp.png]

Comment: I had a similar issue. I cannot figure out what's happening but I managed to remove it by pressing the Alt+F2, type "r" in the command box, and press enter. GNOME should restart and the window will disappear.

Comment: Got this with 20.04.

Notably, popup requesting permission elevation in environment of non-admin user (which is impossible/non-secure). Definitely bug.

Comment: Ok so Alt + F2 + r is a workaround, but how do you actually stop this from happening again?

Comment: @AleksandarNikolic where is this shortcut documented?

Answer (score 28):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then in the resulting box type `r` and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. This will temporarily resolve the issue by restarting the GUI desktop manager.

The underlying cause or bug is not clear yet.

Comment: The workaround helps, thanks. Is there an upstream bug report? I just hit the same issue. Fully updated system. It's 10 months later no bug fix yet?

Comment: @user643011 Not sure if there is one. Feel free to log one! Thanks

Comment: Another option to try is CTRL+ALT+BACKSPACE. Note that doing this will completely restart your desktop environment; all work will be lost.

Comment: I noticed that the rights for my directory does not have the "x" for the "all user" when I had this weird login request the first time. I tried to open a directory that belong to another user and group. No time to do more test so I just leave this info here.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 20.04 I had the same problem of this window opening while wanting to browse some directories.

It  was directories created  after unzipping a zip file (in command line), missing the execute bit in rights.

Applying `chmod +x`  on these directories fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alt+F2 was not opening anything for me, so I opened the System Monitor, found the process `gnome-shell` and ended it. It restarted and the annoying window disappeared.