# gvfsd-admin daemon authentication forces me to restart Ubuntu - VERY annoying!

Tags: services, authentication, gvfs

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a new partition less than a week ago. I have not yet gotten all the basic stuff to work. But now, from time to time, 20.04 pops up a small window saying "Authentication is required to run gvfsd-admin daemon". But even though I enter my Ubuntu password and press  it will not go away. Not even if I press the Cancel-button. Which, by the way, is a bit difficult to do, because instead you activate functions in a window BEHIND the authentication-window(!!) The only way of making the screen usable again is to restart Ubuntu... VERY annoying!

Comment: Essentially the same as https://askubuntu.com/q/1210234/243321 which does not have an answer.

Comment: But apparently a workaround (from Aleksandar Nikolic): "I managed to remove it by pressing the Alt+F2, type "r" in the command box, and press enter. GNOME should restart and the window will disappear."

Comment: Try to erase the content in `rm $HOME/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/*` Another way to check if problem is in $HOME create an test user.

Comment: I have the same bug. The workaround mentioned by @HenrikR works for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [19.10: Does gvfsd-admin require authentication?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1210234/19-10-does-gvfsd-admin-require-authentication)

Comment: Exactly same problem. The annoying thing is the Cancel button doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 50):

This worked for me:

> ... a workaround (from [Aleksandar Nikolic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1210234/19-10-does-gvfsd-admin-require-authentication#comment2097883_1210234)):
>
> > I managed to remove it by pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type "r" in the command box, and press enter. GNOME should restart and the window will disappear.

Comment: Awesome ! Saved me from restarting !

Comment: was worried this was going to nuke all my open apps, but no, just got rid of the auth popup

Answer (score 2):

Another work around for use within the terminal... in case you can't remember the other one, this one will be in your history and can search for it when you need it.

```
killall -3 gnome-shell
```