# How do I close the redundant "authentication required" dialog visible in the corner?

Tags: suspend, authentication

How do I close the redundant "authentication required" dialog visible in the corner?

[image: image of bug]

The way to make this dialog appear is to...

- have a laptop monitor on the right and an external monitor on the left displaying a Firefox browser. This setup involves the HP Zbook on Ubuntu 20.04
- suspend
- press the power button and type in the authentication password
- see the illustrated authentication dialog on the left monitor and note that it partially obscures a browser window but in fact it is not actually preventing use of the browser. It is possible to activate the browser window and click play on the YouTube video
- observe that the authentication dialog cancel button is not functional and attempting to authenticate using a password and the authenticate button is also not working

Comment: Minimize + maximize browser does not get rid of the unwanted dialog.  Unplug + plug the external monitor data cable does not get rid of the unwanted dialog.

Comment: Seems to be a long-standing issue that appears on occasion. There is [a slight work-around](https://askubuntu.com/a/1355440/1222991), but it’s far from ideal 